# Haskell, loading and is this merge function correct?

Tags: haskell

First off I am using ghci under ubuntu 11.10 to run the haskell code. 2nd this is my first attempts at haskell. Third, how might I load a file into ghci and where does it need to be located and what should its extension be? I know ":l "file.haskelxtnsn"" is how to load a file, but that's my best guess so far.

Seeing as I can do the above, how does this code look for merging two list of possibly infinite size in ascending order. (I can't put this in the prelude> prompt because of indentation???) Given [1, 2, 3] and [4, 5, 6] I should get [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], and I think the usage would be "take 10 (merge listx listy)"

```
let merge x y = (min (head x) (head y)) : 
     case (min (head x) (head y)) of 
         head x -> merge (drop 1 x) y 
         head y -> merge x (drop 1 y)
```

psuedo:

- output the min of the heads of the lists
- if the first lists head was output call merge with the rest of the first list and the second
- else call merge with the first list and the rest of the second list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Usually the extension used is ".hs".
- You can use `:cd` in ghci to change directory, you can also supply a path to the `:load` (`:l` for short) command.
- Your logic is correct, although maybe I'd write it a bit differently (hopefully you know about and where clause and defining a function as a series of equations):

  ```
  merge [] ys = ys
  merge xs [] = xs
  merge xs ys = min x y : if x < y then merge (tail xs) ys
                                   else merge xs (tail ys)
          where x = head xs
                y = head ys
  ```
- In ghci you need a `let` in front of definitions, which is different from the `let ... in ...` expression. This is rather confusing so I suggest you just put your code in a file and load it in ghci.
- Function application has higher precedence then the `:` operator, so some of you parenthesis is not needed. We usually try to minimize the number of parenthesis to make the code more concise, but don't be over zealous about it.
- I don't really see the point of using a case expression here (other than causing an error). Try reading on pattern matching for more detail, data constructors vs function applications, why you can't use `head x` inside a pattern but you can do `x:xs` (Although I didn't here). Calling `head` and `min` multiple times looks redundant, andy ou can also substitute `drop 1` with `tail`.

Comment: We are currently looking over pattern matching right now. Its like trying to listen to 13yr girls from the year 3000 talk about their tamagatchis, annoying yet somehow interesting.... But thank you!

Comment: How can I find out what my current directory is in ghci?

Comment: sxu, This code will not load I keep getting errors as such " Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type: a0 = [a0]
    In the first argument of `head', namely `y'
    In the expression: head y
    In an equation for `y': y = head y
"

Comment: @BumSkeeter Sorry, should have tried it myself first, updated. Also in functional programing when dealing with lists, we usually use `x` for an element and `xs` (the plural) for a list. I'm sure you'll pick up more of this along the way...

Comment: Ok sxu, last question. I have loaded my file and got the main> prompt... How do I go back to my prelude> prompt to reload my file after I have changed it?>

Comment: @BumSkeeter Just :reload or :l <file> again.

Comment: Thank you! have a great friday!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to type this into the GHCi prompt, you can do it like this:

```
> let merge x y = (min (head x) (head y)) : case (min (head x) (head y)) of { 
     head x -> merge (drop 1 x) y ; head y -> merge x (drop 1 y) }
```

i.e. using explicit braces in place of indentation (all the above meant to be entered in one unbroken line). When putting the code into a file to be loaded, the leading `let` shouldn't be used.

As to the code itself, it causes an error "Parse error in pattern". This is because `head x` is not a valid pattern.

You can find a `merge` code e.g. [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haskell_features#Mergesort):

```
merge (x:xs) (y:ys) | y < x     = y : merge (x:xs) ys
                    | otherwise = x : merge  xs (y:ys)
merge  xs     []                = xs
merge  []     ys                = ys
```

This preserves duplicates.